# Como usar Url.Action em um Helper Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-helper

Em um projeto ASP.NET MVC5, criei um `Helper` dentro da pasta `App_Code`, porém, ao utilizar a função `Url.Action()` no meu `Helper` ocorre o seguinte erro de compilação:

> CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

Meu código:

```
@helper testeHelper()
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" >teste</a>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do `Helper` não temos acesso aos `Helpers` padrões, para utilizá-los é necessário passar como parâmetro.

O código do `Helper`, fica assim:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@helper testeHelper(UrlHelper Url)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" >teste</a>
}
```

E na sua `View` faz assim para chamar o `Helper`:

```
@MeusHelpers.testeHelper(Url);
```